# Swift 3.0 Error: Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to update my project to Swift 3.0 but I have some difficulties.
I'm getting next error: "Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value".

The problem is inside this function:

```
fileprivate func collectAllAvailable(_ storage: inout [T], nextUrl: String, completion: @escaping CollectAllAvailableCompletion) {
    if let client = self.client {
        let _ : T? = client.collectionItems(nextUrl) {

            (resultCollection, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            guard let resultCollection = resultCollection, let results = resultCollection.results else {
                completion(nil, NSError.unhandledError(ResultCollection.self))
                return
            }

            storage += results // Error: Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value

            if let nextUrlItr = resultCollection.links?.url(self.nextResourse) {

                self.collectAllAvailable(&storage, nextUrl: nextUrlItr, completion: completion) 
                // Error: Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value

            } else {
                completion(storage, nil) 
                // Error: Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil, NSError.unhandledError(ResultCollection.self))
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to fix that?

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for help. So that means that we can't use inout with asynchronous tasks? Also, i'm not sure, but I think that it worked with Swift 2.2. After asynchronous work storage should become equal to new value.

Comment: I have deleted my comments, and compiled them into an answer for you.

Comment: @Hamish thanks a lot! Problem solved, I should use mutable copy.

Comment: Happy to help :) In this case, you don't even need a mutable copy – you can make an immutable copy with the `results` appended onto `storage` (i.e `let storage = storage + results`), as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using an `inout` parameter exclusively for an asynchronous task is an abuse of `inout` – as when calling the function, the caller's value that is passed into the `inout` parameter will not be changed.

This is because `inout` isn't a pass-by-reference, it's just a mutable shadow copy of the parameter that's written back to the caller when the function exits – and because an asynchronous function exits immediately, no changes will be written back.

You can see this in the following Swift 2 example, where an `inout` parameter is allowed to be captured by an escaping closure:

```
func foo(inout val: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        val += "foo"
        completion(val)
    }
}
```

```
var str = "bar"
foo(&str) {
    print($0) // barfoo
    print(str) // bar
}
print(str) // bar
```

Because the closure that is passed to `dispatch_async` escapes the lifetime of the function `foo`, any changes it makes to `val` aren't written back to the caller's `str` – the change is only observable from being passed into the completion function.

In Swift 3, `inout` parameters are no longer allowed to be captured by `@escaping` closures, which eliminates the confusion of expecting a pass-by-reference. Instead you have to capture the parameter by *copying* it, by adding it to the closure's [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/superclass-expression):

```
func foo(val: inout String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {[val] in // copies val
        var val = val // mutable copy of val
        val += "foo"
        completion(val)
    }
    // mutate val here, otherwise there's no point in it being inout
}
```

(**Edit:** Since posting this answer, `inout` parameters can now be compiled as a pass-by-reference, which can be seen by looking at the SIL or IR emitted. However you are unable to treat them as such due to the fact that there's no guarantee *whatsoever* that the caller's value will remain valid after the function call.)

---

However, in your case there's simply no need for an `inout`. You just need to append the resultant array from your request to the current array of results that you pass to each request.

For example:

```
fileprivate func collectAllAvailable(_ storage: [T], nextUrl: String, completion: @escaping CollectAllAvailableCompletion) {
    if let client = self.client {
        let _ : T? = client.collectionItems(nextUrl) { (resultCollection, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            guard let resultCollection = resultCollection, let results = resultCollection.results else {
                completion(nil, NSError.unhandledError(ResultCollection.self))
                return
            }

            let storage = storage + results // copy storage, with results appended onto it.

            if let nextUrlItr = resultCollection.links?.url(self.nextResourse) {
                self.collectAllAvailable(storage, nextUrl: nextUrlItr, completion: completion) 
            } else {
                completion(storage, nil) 
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil, NSError.unhandledError(ResultCollection.self))
    }
}
```

Comment: As an extension for "knowledge-hungries" to your post - this manifesto https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md contains a good remarks about problem that `inout` parameters introduce to Swift optimization. There is a good explanation why `inout` parameter passed-by-reference cannot be treated as such.

Comment: This line of code: `DispatchQueue.main.async {[val] in` does not work for me. I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: @VanDuTran "Does not work" *how* exactly? Compiler error? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Hamish compile error: "Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value".

Comment: @VanDuTran All I can say is that the 3rd code block in my answer compiles just fine in Swift 3. You'll have to show a [mcve] of your particular problem – please ask a new question (stating that you've already seen this Q&A and that it didn't solve your particular problem).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to modify a variable passed by reference in an escaping closure, you can use KeyPath. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
    var num = 1
    func asyncIncrement(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<MyClass, Int>) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Use weak to avoid retain cycle
            [weak self] in
            self?[keyPath: keyPath] += 1
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the full example [here](https://medium.com/@cnliusen/swift-use-keypath-to-modify-a-variable-passed-by-reference-in-escaping-closure-3a6b332659a6).

Comment: Very good idea. KeyPaths are strongly typed so it is safely too.

Answer (score 7):

**If you are sure that your variable will be available the whole time just use a true Pointer (same what `inout` actually does)**

```swift
func foo(val: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary>, completion: @escaping (NSDictionary) -> Void) {
    val.pointee = NSDictionary()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(val.pointee)
    }
}
```