# escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2

I update my project from swift 2.3 to swift 3 and I got "escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value" 
In first recursion call it's run with no error and the second I got this error.this is my code :

```
 static func downloadFiles(_ files:  inout [Links]) 
{
if files.count <= 0 {
            return
        }

        let link = files[0]
        print(link.path)

       let sss = FCFileManager.pathForDocumentsDirectory(withPath: link.localPath)
        FCFileManager.createDirectories(forPath: FCFileManager.pathForDocumentsDirectory(withPath: "\(Const.LAWYERAGENDA)/\(link.type)"))
        if FCFileManager.existsItem(atPath: sss) {
       files.remove(at: 0)
            downloadFiles(&files)
            return
        }
        print(link.path)
        let rr = URLRequest(url: URL(string: link.path)!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: rr, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error.debugDescription)
                    } else {

                        do {
                            FCFileManager.createFile(atPath: sss, overwrite: true)
                            try FCFileManager.writeFile(atPath: sss, content: data as NSObject!, error: ())

                        } catch let err as NSError {
                            print(err.description)
                        }
                    }


            files.remove(at: 0) /escaping closures...
            downloadFiles(&files) /escaping closures...
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: plz post code instead of image

Comment: `inout` parameters are rarely a good idea. In this case you should definitely remove the `inout`.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619714/2880627) show how to modify a pass-by-reference variable in an escaping closure.