# Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value - Assigning inout parameter to local var

Tags: ios, swift3, inout

Looking to assign inout array parameter to local var but getting error

> Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by
>   value

Following is the code

```
func setData( feedsData:  inout [FeedStruct]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.arrData = feedsData // here is the error
    ....
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to understand why you are using `inout` but I strongly suggest you avoid `inout` parameters.  As explained in the duplicate they are especially unsafe when combined with asynchronous execution.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619714/2880627) show how to modify a pass-by-reference variable in an escaping closure.