# Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter

Tags: swift

I have a function like below, but when I perform it , it's show "Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'cani'"
and i missing anything?

```
func duration(out:Int,h2:Int,rep:Int,cani:inout Bool){
        var io = 0
        var b  = 0
        cani = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { // "Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'cani'" //
            timer in
            io += 1
            b  += 1
            if b <= out{
                    text = "come in"
            }else if b <= out + h2 && b > out{
                    text = "Hold on"
            }

            if io == (out + h2 ) * rep{
                textcange = "End"
                timer.invalidate()
                cani = true
            }
        }
}
```

it's show "Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'cani'"

Comment: Did you check these similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39569114/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59943008/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50282040/1187415

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter your function, the cani value is duplicated,
when you exit the function, the duplicated value, potentially modified, is written back. That's what `inout` does.

Your function is asynchronous, so it exits immediately and `cani` is not modified.

When your timer closure is called, first you don't even know if the caller is still living, but you can be sure the `cani` copy that was passed does not exist anymore since the function has already exit a while ago.

The compiler detects this non-sense and tells you to do differently.

You may consider adding a `cani` property in the object that calls the timer, and changes its value in the timer closure or better, since it is asynchronous, call a closure do do what you want to do when the timer issues.

```swift
func duration(out:Int,h2:Int,rep:Int,cani:inout Bool){
    var io = 0
    var b  = 0
    var test: String

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, 
                         repeats: true,
                         completion: (String)->Void) {
        timer in
        io += 1
        b  += 1
        if b <= out {
            text = "Come in"
        } else if b <= out + h2 {
            text = "Hold on"
        }

        if io == (out + h2 ) * rep {
            text = "End"
            timer.invalidate()
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

It's better to put simple and understandable code in StackOverflow questions. And if possible, buildable. ;)