# Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'albums'

Tags: swift, closures

In order to fix this error, [this person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943008/swift-5-escaping-closure-captures-inout-parameter) suggested to change the struct to a class. I did that but I'm still getting the error. How else could I fix this problem?

```swift
class FilmaManager {
    
    let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
    
    func fetchAlbums(albums: inout [Album]) {
        AF.request("\(urlString)/albums").responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                
                //debugPrint(json)
                for album in 0 ..< 100 {
                    let albumId = json[album]["id"].int
                    let albumUserId = json[album]["userId"].int
                    let albumTitle = json[album]["title"].string
                    
                    albums.append(Album(id: albumId ?? 0, userId: albumUserId ?? 0, title: albumTitle ?? ""))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        print(albums)
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `inout` and use a callback closure to return the value. `inout` should be used rarely, this method is basically unusable without a callback that tells you when the work has been completed. You are not even handling errors.

Comment: In that case, how could I use the callback function to apply the value of albums to a tableview's numberOfRows or CellForRowAt function?

Comment: Pass a completion callback that will handle the error (e.g. displaying an alert) and if fetched successfully, appends the fetched album to an array variable inside the table and reloads the table.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks @Sulthan