# How can I use inout instead of Binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I like to know if I could make my view function bind itself via inout instead of Binding, is it possible in right/better syntax for us? right know I am getting compile time error of:

```
Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

which is understandable for me, I thought maybe I am using-wrong syntax for this work.

**PS: I completely know about Binding and it use case, this question try find answer if we could do it with inout as well.**

---

```
func TextView(inPutValue: inout Bool) -> some View {

    return Text("Hello")
        .onTapGesture { inPutValue.toggle() }
    
}
```

---

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isOn: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        
        TextView(inPutValue: &isOn)
 
    }
    
}
```

---

---

**update:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var value: Int = Int() { didSet { print(value.description) } }

    var body: some View {

        Button("update State via inout") { inoutFunction(incomingValue: &value) }
        
    }

}

func inoutFunction(incomingValue: inout Int) { incomingValue += 1 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you can't use `inout` here is because `inout` has a [copy-in-copy-out](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID545) behaviour. The value is passed into the function as a copy, and as soon as the function returns, the modified copy is copied back. You should not think of it as pass-by-reference, thought it can be implemented this way as an optimisation.

Now knowing that, it'd make a lot of sense for the Swift compiler to forbid you from using an inout parameter in an escaping closure, such as using `inPutValue` in `onTapGesture`. After all, the modified `inPutValue` is only copied back when `TextView` returns, not when someone taps it, so whatever modifications you do to it in `onTapGesture` is not visible to the caller of `TextView` at all. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572470/5133585).

So the value is copied back to the caller as soon as `TextView` returns. As the error message says, modifying a `@State` directly when computing `body` (i.e. "during view update") is not allowed.

Now let's look at the case of `Button`. Note that this time, the call to `inoutFunction(incomingValue: &value)` happens inside the button's click handler, rather than in `body` - meaning `value` will be written to when the button is pressed. This is allowed.

You can make your `TextView` to be of a similar form to `Button`'s initialiser by adding a closure argument:

```
func TextView(update: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {

    return Text("Hello")
        .onTapGesture(perform: update)
    
}
```

Note that there is nothing `inout` in this at all, just like there is nothing `inout` in `Button.init`.

You can then write your function with an `inout` parameter:

```
func inoutFunction(_ b: inout Bool) {
    b.toggle()
}
```

and use it:

```
@State private var isOn = true

var body: some View {
    TextView { inoutFunction(incomingValue: &isOn) }
}
```

Notice that you don't *need* `inout` at all.

```
TextView { isOn.toggle() }
```

Comment: WoW! thanks a lot, I just like you see my point of View why I was expecting my code works, because **onTapGesture** is changing the value that is not used in body as render reference, that was my reason that it should works, because I just past a State to **TextView** that has nothing to do in body at all, but after you explained it make all understandable for me now.

Comment: is not this way a game changing? with this way we get access to direct modification without having getter and setters in between, don`t you think so?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What "way" are you talking about? @swiftPunk

Comment: your answer I mean, we could make it in normal Binding way as well!

Comment: @swiftPunk With a binding, you can abstract away the `toggle` call, i.e. the caller doesn't need to write the `isOn.toggle()` call every time. The caller just passes `$isOn`, and the callee knows how to deal with it (what value it should be set).